# Create multiple pipelines for one repository on bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

To any branch I push my code is being deployed to FTP.

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/website
```

How to create multiple pipelines for different branches?

Like **testing** branch to **testing/path**, and **deploy** branch to **deploy/path**.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood it correctly you are looking to trigger pipeline depending on the branch you are working on. I have been doing this as follow:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

pipelines:
  default: # It define rules for all branches that don't have any specific pipeline assigned in 'branches'.
    - step:
        script:
          - mvn -U clean test
  branches:
    master: # It runs only on commit to the master branch.
      - step:
          script:
            - mvn -U clean test
    feature/*: # It runs only on commit to branches with names that match the feature/* pattern.
      - step:
          script:
            - mvn -U clean verify
    live: # It runs only on commit to the live branch
      - step:
          image: python:2.7
          script:
            - chmod +x deploy.bash
            - ./deploy.bash
```

Where the branch name is a [glob pattern](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-globbing_patternsGlobpatternscheatsheet). So you will get decent freedom in matching the right branch.